# How do I access a c# variable's value in an .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

we need to access the c# variable in .aspx page at the time we have problem

Please guide us?

Comment: can you provide some more information about your specific situation? this is a bit vague.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It would help if you gave more detail about what you're trying to do, however you can try this:

First make any variables you want to access in your `aspx` markup `protected`.

Then in the page_load method, call `DataBind();`

Then in your markup you can do this:

```
<%# VariableName %>
```

The "`<%=`" sequence can only be used within certain contexts in server controls. The sequence "`<%#`" is for DataBound controls and can be used in any context in ASPX page markup. Calling `DataBind();` allows you to use this (almost) anywhere on the page.

Comment: i m assigning `regression = (Session["Regression"]).ToString();` in .aspx.cs file
then using it in .aspx file like SelectCommand="SELECT [issue_oid], [issue_num], [regression], 
            [status], [tested_by], [tested_on], [patch_name], [arrived_on], [previous_info], [comment], [is_duplicate] FROM [itt_monthly_patch_issue_list] where status='Not Tested' and `regression='<%#regression%>'"`
but for me it's not working.pls suggest me how to use..

Comment: @picnic4u Please create a new question so I can appropriately answer your question. I don't have enough info to solve your problem via comments and it would be off topic to answer in comments in this user's question.

Comment: please look into my code- i have placed one question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445620/how-can-i-access-string-variable-value-of-aspx-cs-file-in-aspx-file

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something on the page that can be data bound.  Bind that object to it's data source and then you can do an "Eval" on it in the .aspx.

For example, if you have bound your control (presumably in the code-behind) to an object that has a property called "Author", you can display it in the following manner:

```
<asp:TableRow ID="trwMsgAuthor" runat="server">
   <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server" Width="1in">Author:</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="celMsgAuthor"><%#Eval("Author")%></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

The Table in this example is part of an Accordion control where the ".DataSource" property was set to a generic list of objects, of which "Author" was one of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Declare C# code behind variable either public or protected and then us it in `<% %>` block.
e.g.  `<%= strMyCodebehindvariable%>` or `<%# strMyCodebehindvariable%>`. If you are using second option then you must call `DataBind()` method in page load.

Answer (score 0):

In your ASPX, but a `<asp:literal runat=server>` control around your `<%=x %>` code.