# Asp.net get variable from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, if-statement

I want use variables from inherits in asp code

My code looks like that

```
namespace WebApplication2
{

    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
    public bool abcdef = true;   // my variable that i want to use in my asp code      
    ...
    }
}
```

ASP part looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">   
<% 
if(webapplication1.main.abcdef) //this is incorrect, i want to correct that 
{%> 
my first web page 
<%}
else 
{%> 
my second web page 
<%} %>

</html>
```

How can I use my variable `abcdef` in my asp code?

Comment: if you want to use it in javascript you can store its value in ahiddenvaraible and access it at client side.If you just want to output to html (Response.write(abcdef.ToString()) will do

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499261/how-do-i-access-a-c-sharp-variables-value-in-an-aspx-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.Master"
    Inherits="Namespace.YouClass" %>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script>
if(<%#this.abcdef%>)
{
//do your work
}
</script>
```

Comment: I want use this script only inside server  , not clientside 
I want use c# code inside asp code , and i want use variable fom Global class in asp.net code 

for example 
<%
if(webapplication1.main.abcdef) //this is incorect, i want to corect that
{
%>
my frist web page
<%
else
{
%>
my frist web page
<%
}
%>

Comment: if you tell about the scenario it would be easy to answer.