# how can i access string variable value of .aspx.cs file in .aspx file

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

i m getting a string value regression as `regression = (Session["Regression"]).ToString();` in .aspx.cs file then i want to use this value in .aspx file in SelectCommand of SqlDataSource property as below

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [issue_oid], [issue_num], [regression], 
            [status], [tested_by], [tested_on], [patch_name], [arrived_on], [previous_info], [comment], [is_duplicate] FROM [itt_monthly_patch_issue_list] where status='Not Tested' and `regression='<%#regression%>'"`
```

.aspx.cs file page_load method is as below

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if ((Session["UserName"].ToString()) == string.Empty)
            {
                Server.Transfer("regressionType.aspx");
            }
            regression = (Session["Regression"]).ToString();
            usrname = (Session["UserName"]).ToString();
            DataBind();
     }
```

please suggest me how can i do this?
thanks in advance...

Comment: it can de done by  using System.CodeDom,expressionBuilders, similar task i did it once http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-set-dynamic-connectionstring-of.html

Comment: This reminds me of why I hate WebForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you Session Variable's value in your SQLDatasource. Like this Example.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testDatabaseConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserTable] WHERE ([userID] = @UserID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserID" SessionField="UserID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

let us know any other concerns on this..

Answer (score 0):

add Session paramter to your sql Datasource like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource SelectCommand="SELECT [issue_oid], [issue_num], [regression], 
        [status], [tested_by], [tested_on], [patch_name], [arrived_on], [previous_info], [comment], [is_duplicate] FROM [itt_monthly_patch_issue_list] where status='Not Tested' and `regression='<%#regression%>'"`>

<SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="Regression" Name="ParameterName" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: what error you are getting now ? This is the only way, you have to add the session feild to the sqldatasource declaratively ( in the aspx code ) or programatically ( in the code behind).

Comment: SelectCommand="SELECT [issue_oid], [issue_num], [regression], 
            [status], [tested_by], [tested_on], [patch_name], [arrived_on], [previous_info], [comment], [is_duplicate] FROM [itt_monthly_patch_issue_list] where status='Not Tested' and [regression]='<% =regression%>'"
actually the above command is not fetching the data from db because the query having incorrect value for column `regression`
just for confirmation i m printing that value in one label at last on wep page but there it is printing as it is like <%#regression%>

Comment: no need to write regression in this format "<%=regression%>" bcz you have defined it in the select parameters. IF you specify the name Regresion in the session parameter inside the select parameters of sqldatasource then in your select command write the name of parameter which would be Regression. You query should look like SelectCommand="SELECT [issue_oid], [issue_num], [regression], [status], [tested_by], [tested_on], [patch_name], [arrived_on], [previous_info], [comment], [is_duplicate] FROM [itt_monthly_patch_issue_list] where status='Not Tested' and [regression]='Regression'"

Comment: or go to design view of your webpage, select sqldatasource set it's database property and also set the session feild from there.

Comment: <asp:Label ID="regre" runat="server" Text=" name is `regression`" />
how can i print it on level for testing means it's coming in web page or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13791/discussion-between-waqar-janjua-and-picnic4u)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SelectCommand="SELECT [issue_oid], [issue_num], [regression], 
                [status], [tested_by], [tested_on], [patch_name], [arrived_on], [previous_info], [comment], [is_duplicate] FROM [itt_monthly_patch_issue_list] where status='Not Tested' and `regression='<%=ReturnRegression()%>'"`
```

In codebehind:

```
    string regression=null;//Before Page_Load

    protected string ReturnRegression()
    {
    //Write logic here to prevent null being returned
        return regression;
    }
```

Comment: not working.is there anything i have to do for `<form id="form1" runat="server">` like get or set method????

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public StringBuilder regression = new StringBuilder();
regression.Append((Session["Regression"]).ToString());
```

Then in the .aspx page (in the selct command), you can use "regression" as:

```
 <% =regression %>
```

Comment: still not fetching the data from DB bcoz regression value is not coming from aspx.cs page to aspx page

Comment: check the 3rd post at this link: [link] (http://forums.asp.net/t/1115044.aspx/1) .. Hope it helps you

Comment: try the following search in google: "get string variable from code behind to sqldatasource" .. you'll get good results.