# Defaulting hidden field value using inline server code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page where I defined a property in the code behind as follows:

```
    public int testProperty { get; set; }
```

In my page I define a hidden field and want to set the value using an inline server code as follows:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hftestProperty" runat="server" Value="<%= testProperty.ToString() %>" />
```

The problem I am having is that when the control renders in the browser, it renders the value the same way I defined it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hftestProperty" value="<%= testProperty.ToString() %>">
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<input id="hftestProperty" type="hidden" value="<%=testProperty.ToString()%>" />
```

it render:

```
<input id="hftestProperty" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to set the value of the hidden field in the code behind, for example in the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     hftestProperty.Value = testProperty.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: This did work, but I was hoping to do it using the inline server side code.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might need to cast testProperty to string for hidden field. If you are going to use the string value of testProperty at Server then testProperty.ToString() will always be available to you.

Try following code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hftestProperty" value="<%= testProperty%>" />
```

For more info you may see this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499261/how-do-i-access-a-c-sharp-variables-value-in-an-aspx-page)