# Invalid Expression term 'string' when i assign variable in client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, variables, syntax-error

How can i assign variable in aspx page?

See i have tried

```
 <div>
      <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" Text="xxx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <%= string ss=  UsernameTextBox.Text.ToString() %>
      <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" 
           OnClientClick="LoginPopup( <%=  UsernameTextBox.Text  %>);  return false;"
           CssClass="login-button" Text="xxx">
      </asp:Button>
 </div>
```

I have assigned usernametextbox value in string

```
 <%= string ss =  UsernameTextBox.Text.ToString() %>
```

But it's showing error like : *Invalid Expression term 'string'*

Why i can't do that? Is it possible?

But if i remove the `"string ss= "` then it's `<%=  UsernameTextBox.Text.ToString() %>` working good.

I can't assign the values to a string variable. Why?

Is a bug in .net?or any wrong syntax format?

Comment: this answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499261/how-do-i-access-a-c-sharp-variables-value-in-an-aspx-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have to assign a value to variable then you should use normal script tag like:

```
<% string ss = UsernameTextBox.Text.ToString(); %>
```

Later if you want to render that value then you can do:

```
<%= ss %>
```

You  may see: [Embedded Code and Inline Server Tags](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx)

Comment: Gooood. Now i get the value `<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClientClick="LoginPopup( '<% ss  %>');  return false;"
                CssClass="login-button" Text="xxx"></asp:Button>` .but it's not working

Comment: @RameshRajendran, it should be `<%=`, not just `<%`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to be rather non-so-elegant Spaghetti code, your logic is also flawed and you will always get the initial textbox value, not the current value at the time of clicking.

To kill two birds in one shot and have both better code style and working code, first change the markup to be just this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClientClick="return LoginPopup();" CssClass="login-button" Text="xxx"></asp:Button>
```

Now have this in your JS function:

```
function LoginPopup() {
    var name = document.getElementById("<%=UsernameTextBox.ClientID%>").value;
    //...code using the name here...
    return false;
}
```

You read the value at the time of clicking now.

Comment: So don't use it. I just show more elegant way for the sake of those who will want to use it. Also, see what happens if the user name contains a single quote. (hint: your code will break, this code will not)